# Localize with only one language

Tags: javascript, html

I have a short question on how I should approach this problem:

I am creating a Webapplication (pure Frontend) and there is quite some text on it but only one language.

Having only one language it tend to not use localization, but having these long textblocks in code isn't fun either.

So what would be the best practise? Always use localization, with long textblocks?

Btw.: The text is being created so I don't have it while creating the application.

Thanks,
Koanbock

Comment: I think you're confusing the subject at hand. Localization, while possible to do with separate text/content-files mapped to either constants or just variables, are not the same as loading text into the app using constants and variabled. The former is localization, which changed the language based on the user's preferences, the second is just an easier way to input long strings of content.